# how to get the multiple value of a database as a hyperlink in classic asp

Tags: html, asp-classic, oracle11g

I have a query which will select the values of database. The query is as follows.
STRSQL= "SELECT ROLL_NO,STUDENT_NAME FROM STUDENT_MASTER ORDER BY ROLL_NO"

And the html file is as follows

```
             <td><b>Roll No</td>
             <td><b>Name</td>

    </tr>
    <%While Not rs.eof %>
    <tr align="center" class="tb2">
        <td><%response.write rs("ROLL_NO")%></td>
        <td><%response.write rs("STUDENT_NAME")%></td>

    </tr>
    <%
    rs.movenext
    Wend %>
```

Now in this How can I get a data from the database as a hyperlink.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to show the student name as a link,

```
   <%While Not rs.eof %>
    <tr align="center" class="tb2">
         <td><%=rs("ROLL_NO")%></td>
        <td><a href="your_filename_to_link_to"><%=rs("STUDENT_NAME")%></a></td>

    </tr>
    <%
    rs.movenext
    Wend %>
```

`<% =something %>` is same as `<% Response.write something %>`

And if you want to pass the roll_id to the next page:

```
<td><a href="your_filename_to_link_to.asp?roll_no=<%=rs("ROLL_NO")%>"><%=rs("STUDENT_NAME")%></a></td>
```